# Extracting activations from a specific layer of neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I was working on an image recognition problem. After training the model, I saved the architecture as well as weights. Now I want to use the model for extracting features from other images and perform SVM on that. For this, I want to remove the last two layers of my model and get the values calculated by the CNN and fully connected layers till then. How can I do that in Keras?

Answer (score 2):

```
# a simple model
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input((32,32,3)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

# after training
feature_only_model = keras.models.Model(model.inputs, model.layers[-2].output)
```

feature_only_model take a (32,32,3) for input and the output is the feature vector

Comment: what should I pass model.inputs here? I don't understand.

Comment: the new model will have 1 input layer, 1 conv and 1 flattn layer from the original one. you just use the new model as same as the old one.

Answer (score 0):

If your model is subclassed - just change `call()` method.

If not:

1. if your model is complicated - wrap your model by subclassed model and change forward pass in `call()` method, or
2. if your model is simple - create model without the last layers, load weights to every layer separately